# TypeScript "Property does not exist on type" error when setting up a "Profile Details" page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know this is an extremely simple question but I have yet to find a resource solution that will work or explain in a way that makes complete sense. I'm trying to get back into Angular after many years and never used TypeScript before. Currently struggling a lot with errors and what TypeScript is actually expecting me to do.

I have an app that connects to the [Open Brewery DB](https://www.openbrewerydb.org/). I'm trying to make a details page that fetches data based on an `:id` URL param.

- `app.com/breweries`, give me a list of breweries
- `app.com/breweries/:id`, give me specific details on that brewery

I have a list component that grabs a [list of Breweries](https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries). So whatever comes back gets displayed in a list.

**http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { IBrewery } from './brewery/brewery';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getBreweries() {
        return this.http.get('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries');
    }

    getBrewery(id) {
        return this.http.get<IBrewery[]>(`https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/${id}`)
    }
}
```

**list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

    breweries: Object;

  constructor(private _http: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this._http.getBreweries().subscribe(data => {
            this.breweries = data;
        });
  }

}
```

**list.component.html**

```
<h1>Breweries</h1>

<ul *ngIf="breweries">
    <li *ngFor="let brewery of breweries">
        <p class="name">{{ brewery.name }}</p>
        <p class="country">{{ brewery.country}}</p>
        <a href="{{brewery.website_url}}" class="site" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So all this works no errors everything seems fine...then comes the profile and where things break down.

**brewery.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-brewery',
  templateUrl: './brewery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./brewery.component.scss']
})

export class BreweryComponent implements OnInit {

    brewery: object = {};
    breweryId: string;

  constructor(private _http: HttpService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.breweryId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
        this._http.getBrewery(this.breweryId).subscribe(data => {
            this.brewery = data;
        })
    }

}
```

**brewery.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="brewery">
    <li>
        {{brewery.name}}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{brewery.city}}, {{brewery.state}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**brewery.ts**

```
export interface IBrewery {
    name: string,
    city: string,
    state: string
};
```

The errors I'm getting are:
- `ERROR in src/app/brewery/brewery.component.html:7:13 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.`
- `Error occurs in the template of component BreweryComponent.
    src/app/brewery/brewery.component.html:10:13 - error TS2339: Property 'city' does not exist on type 'object'.`
- `Error occurs in the template of component BreweryComponent.
    src/app/brewery/brewery.component.html:10:31 - error TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'object'.`

So the problem I believe is that `brewery` needs to have assigned properties and types associated to those properties before I can declare them in the component template. If that is true, for the life of me I cannot figure out how or where I'm supposed to take the `IBrewery` and properly use it. I've seen examples where it gets used in the `service` as well as the `mycomponent.component.ts` file. In either instance it's about as clear as mud on how to fix the problem.

Comment: Since you're setting brewery to an empty object the component initialized with that value and it doesn't have any properties. Change this in your brewery component "brewery: object = {};" to this "brewery: object;" I like this better than the 'safe navigation' option because it feels hacky to me to ngif something that is never undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately `brewery: object = {}` still has errors.

In either instance TypeScript is still rendering the follow errors
 
Error occurs in the template of component BreweryComponent.
src/app/brewery/brewery.component.html:13:30 - error TS2339: Property 'state' 
does not exist on type 'object'.

I've also reset the brewery property with and without the `*ngIf="loader"` solution

Comment: Looks like `brewery: any = {};` works....feel like this isn't a proper fix though.

Comment: What happens if you do just this. brewery: IBrewery;

Comment: I've since added an interface after some trial and error

`brewery = <IBrewery>{};` <-- I'm guessing this is attaching those properties from the interface to an empty object so TypeScript knows what is up.   

Which then I got errors in `this.brewery = this.data` so I've updated that line with the spread operator `this.brewery={...data}`. The reason I went with the spread operator is I didn't want to destructor the data object and then define each like `this.brewery={name,city,state...}`

Comment: As a follow up, looks like I'm getting expected errors in the template when I define properties outside the interface. So for example `website_url` is a property in the response object, but I don't have declared in the interface. So `<a href="{{brewery.website_url}}">Visit Site</a>` throws an error stating `website_url` isn't part of the interface. So this feels like what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should get the correct typing in your service. It should look like this:

```
getBreweries() {
    return this.http.get<IBrewery[]>('https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries');
}

getBrewery(id) {
    return this.http.get<IBrewery>(`https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries/${id}`)
}
```

As you can see, I added the expected type to `getBreweries` and changed the expected type in `getBrewery(id)`. I'm not sure why it was set to `IBrewery[]` before, since you told us it should only give one specific detail of a brewery.

Now, when you subscribe to these, the parameter inside the subscibe function will be inferred to be the types you have set in the `get` type parameter. Therefore, it's a good idea to set the type of the component instance variable to that type too, like this:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

    breweries: IBrewery[];
    ...
}
```

and

```
export class BreweryComponent implements OnInit {

    brewery: IBrewery;
    ...
}
```

In general, you don't want to use the type `object` or `Object`, because it tells you nothing about the structure of the type. If you don't know the exact structure of your type or are too lazy to create an interface, you should use `any`.

And btw, the reason why the ListComponent worked to begin with was kinda lucky. the `let x of y` syntax is allowed for `y` of type `object` for some reason, and it seems like `x` is inferred to as `any`, so you could write whatever you wanted without getting an error. It's important to understand that typescript won't change anything in runtime, so the runtime types will be whatever they are no matter what your typescript types say.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: use [Safe Navigation Operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

Update your html as below.

```
<ul *ngIf="brewery">
    <li>
        {{brewery?.name}}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{brewery?.city}}, {{brewery?.state}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Better approach: use a loading spinner.

```
<div *ngIf="loading">
  some loading spinner
</div>

<div *ngIf="!loading">
    <li>
        {{brewery?.name}}
    </li>
    <li>
        {{brewery?.city}}, {{brewery?.state}}
    </li>
</ul>


export class BreweryComponent implements OnInit {

    brewery; // be default type will be any. 
    breweryId: string;
    loading = false; // loading spinner.

    constructor(private _http: HttpService, 
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.breweryId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
        this.get();

    }

    get() {

        this.loading = true;
        this._http.getBrewery(this.breweryId)
             .subscribe(data => {

            this.brewery = data;
            this.loading = false; // loading spinner hidden.

        }, (error) => {

            // handle error;

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this approach is also rendering TypeScript errors.

```
  Error occurs in the template of component BreweryComponent.
src/app/brewery/brewery.component.html:13:30 - error TS2339: Property 'state' 
does not exist on type '{}'.

13         {{brewery?.city}}, {{brewery?.state}}
```

Comment: check the updated one. changed type of brewery to any